How to replace multiple special chars in a string
I am trying to replace special characters in a string, but there are different occurences and differents characters. The actual code will only replace the first special character encountered, whereas i would like to replace all special characters in the string.
Edit : All answers i get are specific to this string, whereas my answer will work for any string ! Thanks everyone, problem solved !
titre = "4K ULtra HD | SAMSUNG UHD Demo׃ LED TV"
print("original : "+ titre)
chars=["?",":","*","~","|","#","/","\""]
for i in chars:
    if i in titre:
        titre=titre.replace(i,"-")
print("modified : "+ titre)

#Output : modified : 4K ULtra HD - SAMSUNG UHD Demo׃ LED TV

This will only replace the "|" and not the ":", expected result is:
4K ULtra HD - SAMSUNG UHD Demo- LED TV


In the string titre the colon is not the same See https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+05C3 VS https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+003A

Just tried running your code. Encountered the same issue. But when I removed the colon and typed it again, then ran the code, the issue seems to get resolved.          \n original : 4K ULtra HD | SAMSUNG UHD Demo: LED TV
\n modified : 4K ULtra HD - SAMSUNG UHD Demo- LED TV

I wonder why people downvote ? Could you explain ?  Because i didn't know there was many colon formats ? Who is supposed to know this ?

I did not downvote but I think people (myself included) looked at your code and saw what they thought was an easy alternative approach to a common challenge. Alternatively, some editors (vscode for one) will highlight unicode characters that visually duplicate common characters to help prevent these types of issues.

@JonSG I use Python IDLE to code... And i don't think giving an answer that will work for any occurences of any special chars is a waste of time.

Thanks to The fourth bird and hojkas !
I understood what was going wrong and i finally ended up with this working code (for any special characters but keep spaces) :
titre = '4K UL*tra & H~~~~D | SAMS!!!!UNG U,HD De;mo׃ LE$D T^^V'
print('original : '+ titre)
for i in titre:
    if not i.isalnum() and not i.isspace():
        titre=titre.replace(i,'')
print('modified : '+ titre)

#Output : 
#original : 4K UL*tra & H~~~~D | SAMS!!!!UNG U,HD De;mo׃ LE$D T^^V
#modified : 4K ULtra  HD  SAMSUNG UHD Demo LED TV


Sidenote for cleaner looking code: Consider writing the if conditions into one, and using the not operator: if not i.isalnum() and not i.isspace():

You could achieve this by using the sub() functionality of the re package.
The issue you're seeing is due to the fact that what appears to be an ASCII colon is, in fact, a HEBREW PUNCTUATION SOF PASUQ with a Unicode value of 05C3
Therefore:
import re

titre = "4K ULtra HD | SAMSUNG UHD Demo׃ LED TV"
PATTERN = r"[\?:\*~\|#/\"\u05c3]"

print(re.sub(PATTERN, "-", titre))

Output:
4K ULtra HD - SAMSUNG UHD Demo- LED TV


Yes, i didn't know it was an ASCII colon, well i didin't know there were many colon formats... Someone told me and i answered with python methods to catch any special char. thanks by the way :)


How to replace multiple chars in a string?

The problem can be fixed.
Easier way to do this.
Snippet:
titre  = "4K ULtra HD | SAMSUNG UHD Demo׃ LED TV"
chars_to_replace = {"|": "-", "\u05c3": "-"}
result_string = "".join([chars_to_replace.get(char, char) for char in titre ])
print(result_string)

Output:
4K ULtra HD - SAMSUNG UHD Demo- LED TV

